# Convert Ruby string to *nix filename-compatible string

Tags: ruby, string, filenames

In Ruby I have an arbitrary string, and I'd like to convert it to something that is a valid Unix/Linux filename. It doesn't matter what it looks like in its final form, as long as it is visually recognizable as the string it started as. Some possible examples:

```
"Here's my string!" => "Heres_my_string"
"* is an asterisk, you see" => "is_an_asterisk_you_see"
```

Is there anything built-in (maybe in the file libraries) that will accomplish this (or close to this)?

Comment: On most Linux file systems the only characters not allowed in filenames are `\0` and `/`. `* is an asterisk, you see` is a perfectly valid filename.

Comment: @sepp2k: Good point. In that case, I want to make a file that's possible for someone to move or delete without pulling out all their hair :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By your specifications, you could accomplish this with a regex replacement. This regex will match all characters other than basic letters and digits:

```
s/[^\w\s_-]+//g
```

This will remove any extra whitespace in between words, as shown in your examples:

```
s/(^|\b\s)\s+($|\s?\b)/\\1\\2/g
```

And lastly, replace the remaining spaces with underscores:

```
s/\s+/_/g
```

Here it is in Ruby:

```
def friendly_filename(filename)
    filename.gsub(/[^\w\s_-]+/, '')
            .gsub(/(^|\b\s)\s+($|\s?\b)/, '\\1\\2')
            .gsub(/\s+/, '_')
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is the "i" necessary in the first `gsub`?

Comment: Oh, it isn't. I thought `\w` corresponded only to `[a-z0-9]` but it actually is `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Thanks for pointing that out — I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This also removes the . (period) between the filename and its extension

Comment: @JoshL Yeah the lack of period encoding burned me with this regex.  Would love a replacement to this .gsub that preserves the period as another file-compatible character to preserve uniqueness.

Answer (score 10):

First, I see that it was asked purely in ruby, and second that it's not the same purpose (*nix filename compatible), but if you are using Rails, there is a method called `parameterize` that should help.

In rails console:

```
"Here's my string!".parameterize => "here-s-my-string"
"* is an asterisk, you see".parameterize => "is-an-asterisk-you-see"
```

I think that parameterize, as being compliant with URL specifications, may work as well with filenames :)

You can see more about here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize

There's also a whole lot of another helpful methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Zaru Gem](https://github.com/madrobby/zaru).

```
Zaru.sanitize! "  what\ēver//wëird:user:înput:"
# => "whatēverwëirduserînput"

Zaru.sanitize!("* is an asterisk, you see")
# => " is an asterisk, you see"
```